# Defining a function for different containers

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I want to define a function that accepts different types of containers: those that own the data (like `std::vector`) and those that don't (like `boost::iterator_range`).

I wrote the following:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

template<typename C>
void fill(C& c, typename C::value_type v){
    for (auto& j : c)
        j = v;
}


template<typename C>  // How to avoid this implementation?
void fill(const C& c, typename C::value_type v){
    for (auto& j : c)
        j = v;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    auto rng = boost::make_iterator_range(v.begin(), v.end());


    fill(v, 1);  // Case 1 -- Calling on std::vector
    fill(rng, 2); // Case 2 -- Calling on boost::iterator_range

    // Case 3 -- Calling with an r-value, requires the overload
    fill(boost::make_iterator_range(v.begin(), v.end()), 3);

    // Case 4 -- Should not be allowed
    // fill(std::vector<int>(10), 4);
}
```

My first implementation of `fill` works well, in that it accepts both kinds of iterators.

However, since `boost::iterator_range` does not own the data, it can be `const` (while the data is non-const) and so I would like to allow rvalues as arguments. This means that I need the second implementation.

Is this the only way to do this? Is there a way to avoid the second implementation?

Comment: If you want to allow rvalues as input, then you should have an overload that takes an rvalue reference as a parameter.  In any case, in both versions shown, `v` should be taken as a const reference.

Comment: Yes, I am just wondering if there’s a better way of implementing the overload to avoid code repetition. Also, as far as I understand having a const reference implementation only would not work with an std::vector.

Comment: I said you should pass the `v` parameter, not the `c` parameter, as a const reference since `v` is a read-only parameter in all cases.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. I understand now, thanks for the comment but that’s really besides the point of my question.

Comment: For the `c` parameter, since it is templated, look into ["universal/forwarding references"](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), which can take either an lvalue or an rvalue as input, depending on the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename C>
void fill(C&& c, typename std::decay_t<C>::value_type v) {
    for (auto& j : c)
        j = v;
}
```

> This isn't actually "perfectly forwarding" since you're not looking to take advantage of move semantics, if you wanted to you should write `std::forward<C>(c)` instead of `c`¹

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23cd930cc6ea16bd)**

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <vector>

template <typename C>
void fill(C&& c, typename std::decay_t<C>::value_type v) {
    for (auto& j : c)
        j = v;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    auto rng = boost::make_iterator_range(v.begin(), v.end());

    fill(v, 1);   // Case 1 -- Calling on std::vector
    fill(rng, 2); // Case 2 -- Calling on boost::iterator_range

    // Case 3 -- Calling with an l-value, requires the overload
    fill(boost::make_iterator_range(v.begin(), v.end()), 3);
}
```

---

¹ Note that you have to be careful not to use-after-move if you do.

Comment: Thanks. I read more about universal references as @Remy Lebeau suggested. They almost handle all the cases, except for "Case 4" which I added. Namely,  with a "universal reference", `fill` works with an `std::vector<int>(10)` as argument.  Before, I prevented this by making r-values const (and then the iterators are constant). Is there a way to combine both approaches? Namely, make the function accept an "lvalue" or a "constant rvalue"?

Comment: PS: Just realized that I do this with a `fill_impl` that takes a universal reference and is called by the two overloads of `fill` above (with an lvalue and a const rvalue). Just wondering, for educational purposes, if there's some template magic that could solve this.

Comment: Yeah here's my take, just to verify that you had the same idea: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29552be3abdb5ce2 - you can use a static_assert to make it fail even if no assignment is attempted: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57ff76fbb44df62d

Comment: My rule of thumb with meta-programming: explicit is good. The more implicit magic you strive for, the more painful surprises you will run into. If everything is explicit dispatch then it's "always" easy to solve

Comment: agreed, although I do think using meta-programming (like `std::conditional` or `std::enable_if`) can improve readability. I changed the [implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4a6ed7179443d17) a bit to avoid the dispatch overload (I have multiple functions using the same idiom so I am looking for a solution that avoid repetition). I do this by defining a `const_rvalue` which returns a constant type when the passed argument is an rvalue. Unfortunately, I cannot get rid of the dispatch completely.

Comment: Actually, getting rid of the dispatch is [trivial](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e07fe659d10a440). I like this solution, assuming it is correct :)

Comment: @Tohiko Looks good to me. Very succinct. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the case where `*c.begin()` is a const reference.

```
template<typename C>
void fill_impl(C& c, typename C::value_type v, std::false_type){
    for (auto& j : c)
        j = v;
}

template<typename C>
void fill_impl(C& c, typename C::value_type v, std::true_type) = delete;

template<typename C>
void fill(const C& c, typename C::value_type v){
    fill_impl(c, v, std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*c.begin())>>{});
}

template<typename C>
void fill(C& c, typename C::value_type v){
    fill_impl(c, v, std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*c.begin())>>{});
    // hopefully always true_type, but you never know
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3426b04056b4240)

Comment: Thanks! This is an interesting method but it is difficult to scale with multiple containers as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For my (and others'(?)) future reference. I found the following solution to tick all my boxes: Accepts lvalues and rvalues making sure that rvalues are constant, also without need for dispatch functions.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using const_if_rvalue = typename std::conditional<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value,
                                                  const std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<T>>;

template<typename C>
void fill(C&& cr, typename std::decay_t<C>::value_type const& v){
    typename const_if_rvalue<C>::type& c = cr;
    for (auto& j : c)
        j = v;
}


int main(){
    typedef std::vector<int> array;
    typedef boost::iterator_range<array::iterator> range;
    array v(10);
    range rng = boost::make_iterator_range(v.begin(), v.end());

    fill(v, 1);  // Case 1 -- Calling on std::vector
    fill(rng, 2); // Case 2 -- Calling on the range

    // Case 3 -- Calling with an l-value, requires the overload
    fill(boost::make_iterator_range(v.begin(), v.end()), 3);

    // Case 4 -- Should not be allowed
    // fill(std::vector<int>(10), 4);
}
```